# Why does my Android custom adapter style random rows?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a simple custom adapter that I'm using to display a list of degrees. I'm trying to add a way to make a sort of sub title in the list to group like content together. Each row has a title and a description, so what I'm trying to do is when it inflates a row that has description set to null, it changes the style of the row (hides the description and centers the title). The problem I'm running into is that is applies the style to random rows instead of just the ones with the null value (the title on random rows will be centered and the description on other random rows will be hidden)
My getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.links_list, null);
    }

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView tvDesc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

    if(mainList.get(position) instanceof Program) {
        Program row = (Program) mainList.get(position);
        if(row.getTitle() != null && row.getType() == null) {
            //this condition should style just the ones with null type, but style random rows instead
            tvTitle.setText(row.getTitle());
            tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tvDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if(row.getTitle() != null) {
                tvTitle.setText(row.getTitle());
            }
            if(row.getType() != null) {
                tvDesc.setText(row.getType());
            }
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

So my question is, why does this style random rows instead of just the ones I tell it to?

Comment: rethink your if else conditions

Comment: And the views in a listview are reused, so please undo that Gravity conditions in your "normal View" `tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tvDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Could you elaborate on the if else conditions? I don't see what's wrong with them, the objects to be treated as a sub header will have a null type and a value for title.

Comment: ok, so undo your gravity stuff on normal views, because views are reused.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by undo the gravity? You mean take out those two lines that set gravity and visibility? How do I style a single row conditionally then?

Comment: No no, u are giving the view a gravity if its a title, but you have to give the exact other way aorund if its not a title in else statement, because THE VIEWS ARE REUSED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mainList.get(position) instanceof Program) {
        Program row = (Program) mainList.get(position);
        if(row.getTitle() != null && row.getType() == null) {
            //this condition should style just the ones with null type, but style random rows instead
            tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvTitle.setText(row.getTitle());
            tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tvDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvTitle.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            tvDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(row.getTitle() != null) {
                tvTitle.setText(row.getTitle());
            }
            if(row.getType() != null) {
                tvDesc.setText(row.getType());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ohh, I think I see what you mean by the view is reused now. Let me see if I got it straight...so if I set visibility to GONE, the next row that inflates will still use GONE. I just assumed it reset to the xml layout each time it went through this code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes thats the point. You have to set the Visibility to visible if you want it to be visible. XML will not be reloaded, because the view is gona be reused